# SaferCreateLevel SAFER_LEVELID_UNTRUSTED: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142)

Tags: security, winapi, uac

i'm trying to launch a process (*any* process) as "**untrusted**" using the [`SaferCreateLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `SAFER_LEVELID_UNTRUSTED` safer level:

> Allows programs to execute with access only to resources granted to open well-known groups, blocking access to **Administrator** and **Power User** privileges and personally granted rights.

Using the code from Michael Howards DropMyRights MDSN article ([Browsing the Web and Reading E-mail Safely as an Administrator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972827.aspx)) the pseudo-code is:

```
//get a handler on a Safer level
hSaferLevel = SaferCreateLevel(SAFER_SCOPEID_USER, SAFER_LEVELID_UNTRUSTED);

//Create a security token out of the safer level handle
hSecurityToken = SaferComputeTokenFromLevel(hSaferLevel);

//Create process as user
CreateProcessAsUser(hSecurityToken, "myapp.exe");
```

Except that the process fails to launch:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142).

[image]

What's going on here?

**Note:** Launching a process at the `SAFER_LEVELID_NORMALUSER` works fine:

> Allows programs to execute as a user that does not have **Administrator** or **Power User** user rights. Software can access resources accessible by normal users.

Although since everyone already runs as a "*Normal User*" these days, there's little value in it.

---

My application **is** able to handle running as a "low" user.

The end goal was to run the process with the same privelages as a **MandatoryIntegrity\Low** process would get (although not tagged as "low"). So i tested that.

i used `icacls` to mark [my application to run **Mandatory Integrity Level\Low**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625960.aspx):

```
C:\Develop>icacls RTMS.exe /setintegritylevel Low
processed file: RTMS.exe
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

And my application launches correctly, and is running at the low integrity level:

[image]

While i might be able to use the [`AddMandatoryAce`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2006/10/24/modifying-the-mandatory-integrity-level-for-a-securable-object-in-windows-vista.aspx) API, or fiddle with the ACLs in the security token myself, i'm curious what's up with an `UNTRUSTED` Safer level - and why i can't get anything to launch.

**Note:** On Windows 7 if you mark `calc` or `notepad` as `/setintegritylevel low` they will fail to launch (no error, just never appear), even [though this MSDN article talks about using calc as a test of low integrity level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625960.aspx):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0xc0000142` = `STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED`

Maybe [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) will give you some clues?

`UNTRUSTED` is probably too restriced for most things. You can't access your own profile, e.g.:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER
- %temp%

Did you try `CONSTRAINED`?

Another alternative is to use [CreateRestrictedToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and compute a token that is just restrictive enough.

I'm guessing that MS sort of forgot about the Safer*Level functions in NT6 and we got UAC instead. (The RunAs GUI dialog on XP had the protect my computer option, but that dialog box is now gone (Even in XP, it was [too restrictive](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2004/09/10/227727.aspx) for most things))

Comment: i did try `constrained`; it works, but it also has more permissions that i'd like. On the other hand `untrusted` seems too restrictive. i guess it's quite conceivable that there's no **Safer** level that matches the permission gives to a `MandatoryIntegrityLevel\Low` process.

Comment: Hmm, i had tried Process Monitor for trying to figure out why **calc** wouldn't launch as `Low` anymore; i didn't think of trying to see why my application (which can launch as `Low`) failed to launch as "constrained". Probably all adds up to the fact that no `Safer` level can be used to mimic the restrictions of `Low`.

Comment: A spawned process inherits the integrity level of its parent process unless the token used to spawn the process says otherwise.  Use `SaferComputeTokenFromLevel()` to create a `SAFER_LEVELID_NORMALUSER` token and then use `SetTokenInformation()` to set the token's Integrity Level to Low.